# MySQL Server crashes and fails to start - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, phpmyadmin

I have been using mySQL for a few weeks now with PHPMyAdmin with no problems. But just lately it stopped working - MySQL server will run for a few seconds when I start my machine (Mac OS X 10.9.5)then it crashes and wont restart. It also wont let me log in PHPMyAdmin.

When i try to run mysql through terminal it returns the following error:

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock

I'm not really sure what could cause this after it working for so long.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-m

Comment: When installing from scratch I had that error, and my problem was mysql user account did not have read permission on the /tmp directory. This page helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-m

Comment: When i run "nano Stephens-MacBook-Pro-2.local.err" it returns an error saying "Permission Denied"

Comment: Also when I run "chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data", it returns "Operation not permitted" on all the files

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` on the command line/terminal is just another MySQL client, like phpMyAdmin or your web application. The error you're seeing is the same error as phpMyAdmin is displaying. On linux/OSX the command is actually `mysqld` (d for Daemon or server).

**Homebrew/Macports/etc installs**

During installation it should have installed a [launchctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) script. Find it on the terminal with `ls ~/Library/LaunchAgents/` and inspect the output, in my case:

```
homebrew.mxcl.lighttpd.plist
homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
homebrew.mxcl.php55.plist
```

There in the middle - now I can use `launchctl` to start it at the terminal:

```
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Although the handy launchctl script is called "mysql" it's actually launching `mysqld`, usually from `/usr/local/bin/mysqld`

**Standard MySQL install**

If you installed MySQL directly from their website, you should have a "MySQL" option in your System Preferences. From there you can stop/start the service.
If you didn't install mysqld with a package manager, perhaps you installed/compiled it yourself, then search your disk for `mysqld` and launch it from the command line or find an `init.d` folder with a mysqld script inside.

Comment: Ok so when I run ls ~/Library/LaunchAgents/, theres is no mysql.plist....only ones for Adobe, Google and Spotify

Comment: @Stephen How was the MySQL server installed? Each method has different ways of managing the process

Comment: As far as i can remember, it was installed using this method : http://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-web-server-in-mountain-lion/

Comment: @Stephen If you go to System Preferences do you have a MySQL option in there? That should have a button to stop/start the MySQL server